# unmet dependencies, I can't install ubuntu-sdk

Tags: installation, ubuntu-sdk, qt5, html5

I have been trying to install the ubuntu developer environment so that I may begin gaining practice in app development. But once I try to install ubuntu-sdk I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-html5-container but it is not going to be installed
```

for which I then proceed to insert the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-html5-container
```

in which I then receive the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-html5-container : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin but it is not installable
```

at which point I would feel logical to insert the command:

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
```

and my new error message is:

```
Package qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I have updated my repository libraries several times and still nothing. Could someone please tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong? Why isn't this working like it should?

Comment: the suggested ticket has a great, general purpose answer, but the issue reported here is very specific. I guess something got broken in the package dependencies, because we installed the SDK some times ago on ubuntu just following the steps from the website (the same steps suggested by @Avinash Raj) and that time it worked fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, so this question isn't specific.

Answer (score 3):

I have the very same issue trying to install **ubuntu-sdk** on a new VM today
The VM is running **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit**

Here how I solved the issue:

- downloaded the packages:

[qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/x11/qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin)

[qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/all/qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets/download)

- installed manually the packages dependencies:

> sudo apt-get install libqt5core5
>
> sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5
>
> sudo apt-get install libqt5qml5
>
> sudo apt-get install libqt5quick5 libqt5sql5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
>
> sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
>
> sudo dpkg -i qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets_0.22+13.10.20131011.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
>
> sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
>
> sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
>
> sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-window-plugin
>
> sudo dpkg -i qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin_0.22+13.10.20131011.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Finally run the command to install the skd:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk

That worked fine for me :)

Comment: I use 13.04 and it worked like a charm

Comment: unfortunately we have to stick to 12.04 as it is the currrent LTS version :)

Answer (score 1):

Try only this command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude; sudo aptitude install ubuntu-sdk
```

Comment: that's what I did, and I got the very same error reported by @HaveYouMetRandy

Comment: but it works for me.Enable the universe repository and  update it,then run the above code.

Comment: I believe you, and actually those are the command on the SDK webpage, but that does not worked for me either.