# Ubuntu 14.04.1 and unmet dependencies for ubuntu sdk. Use Qt Creator instead

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, qt, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to install Ubuntu SDK, but get the same problem like here ([first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359083/packages-have-unmet-dependencies-on-ubuntu-sdk-installation), [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408463/unmet-dependencies-i-cant-install-ubuntu-sdk)). The promoted solution like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) doesn't help me either (

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Ok, I will find the solution if I need, but I more annoyed by the fact that why does it happen? I can't understand where does the problem begin? Does somebody test their software on "easy 3 steps installation"?

It was a lyrical digression..My second question is how can I use just Qt Creator (not Ubuntu SDK which is built on top of them) to create the same Ubuntu Apps?

**Output for @g_p:**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev : Depends: libqt5webkit5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qt3d5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qt5-default but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qtdeclarative5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qtlocation5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qtmultimedia5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qtscript5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qtsensors5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: qttools5-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: (quote) > The promoted solution like this (check this link in the question) doesn't help me either (

Comment: please post the output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev`

Comment: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.126
  Version table:
     1.126 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Try to install this package and post the error.

Comment: see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing in chat with [Timur Fayzrakhmanov](https://askubuntu.com/users/159189/timur-fayzrakhmanov) and [Mateo](https://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo) ([here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17630/room-for-g-p)), [Timur Fayzrakhmanov](https://askubuntu.com/users/159189/timur-fayzrakhmanov) managed to install Ubuntu-SDK.

The problem was with that some packages was not getting  authenticated, which was causing dependency problem. I thank to [Mateo](https://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo) for helping in the chat.